# R function doesn't do what I want

Tags: r

I don't inderstand why my function doesn't work, can you help me to find my error.

```
VehiculeFunction <- function(data){
  my.data <- data[data$GAMME =="M1",]
  ma.col = rgb(red = 0.1,blue = 1,green = 0.1, alpha = 0.2)
  X <- my.data$GMF.24
  Y <- my.data$Cout.24
  X11()
  plot(X, Y, pch=20, las = 1, col = ma.col, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0,10))
  identify(X, Y, labels = my.data$NITG, cex = 0.7)
}
```

This one works perfectly, and when I add two variables it returns "numeric(0)"

```
VehiculeFunction <- function(data, x, y){
  my.data <- data[data$GAMME =="M1",]
  ma.col = rgb(red = 0.1,blue = 1,green = 0.1, alpha = 0.2)
  X <- my.data$x
  Y <- my.data$y
  X11()
  plot(X, Y, pch=20, las = 1, col = ma.col, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0,10))
  identify(X, Y, labels = my.data$NITG, cex = 0.7)
}
VehiculeFunction(data.vehicule, GMF.24, Cout.24)
numeric(0)
```

thank you Oleg, and if i want to add a condition on another variable of my dataframe, i want to take all the three first of "RANG_NITG_PROJET_K"

```
my.data1 <- my.data[my.data$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 1|2|3,] ?
```

but | think it's false because when i do this

```
my.data1 <- data.vehicule[data.vehicule$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 1,]
my.data2 <- data.vehicule[data.vehicule$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 2,]
my.data3 <- data.vehicule[data.vehicule$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 3,]
my.data <- rbind(my.data1, my.data2, my.data3)
```

it gives me two different dataframe ?

Comment: data is a dataframe !

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. Moreover, pass `x` and `y` as characters and use `[` instead of `$` to select the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. You cannot access `my.data` columns (or list elements) using the $ operator in this case and you need to pass strings for `x` and `y`:

```
VehiculeFunction <- function(data, x, y, gamme){
  my.data <- data[data$GAMME == gamme,]
  ma.col = rgb(red = 0.1,blue = 1,green = 0.1, alpha = 0.2)
  X <- my.data[[x]] # <- change from $ to [[]]
  Y <- my.data[[y]] # <- change from $ to [[]]
  X11()
  plot(X, Y, pch=20, las = 1, col = ma.col, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0,10))
  identify(X, Y, labels = my.data$NITG, cex = 0.7)
}

VehiculeFunction(data.vehicule, "GMF.24", "Cout.24", "M1") # <- change to strings
```

Comment: just one more question, i want to add a "gamme" variable, my.data <- data[data$GAMME =="gamme",] seems not working ?

Comment: thank you Oleg, and if i want to add a condition on another variable of my dataframe, i want to take all the three first of "RANG_NITG_PROJET_K" 

my.data1 <- my.data[my.data$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 1|2|3,] ? 

but | think it's false because when i do this 

my.data1 <- data.vehicule[data.vehicule$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 1,]
my.data2 <- data.vehicule[data.vehicule$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 2,]
my.data3 <- data.vehicule[data.vehicule$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K == 3,]
my.data <- rbind(my.data1, my.data2, my.data3)

it gives me two different dataframe ?

Comment: Try something like `df[df$COL %in% c(1, 2, 3),]`